# Set progress in ProgressWheel for download files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I have a list view. When user selects an item of my list view, I open DetailActivity that user can download a file in that activity and I show the user download percentage using `ProgressWheel`.

My problem is when user closes the activity and then returns back to activity, the `ProgressWheel` doesn't update anymore.
Here is my code:(I download the file using AsynchTask)

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                String link = params[0];
                fileExtention = getFileExtention(link);
                url = new URL(link);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            // set some parameters for httpUrlConnection
            connection.setConnectTimeout(JSONConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setReadTimeout(JSONConstants.READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.connect(); // Connection Complete here.!
            // Get from Server and Catch In Input Stream Object.
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH); 
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            File outputFile = new File(file, "fileTitle"
                    + ".mp3" );
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    outputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length = 0;
            long total = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                total += length;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                if (lenghtOfFile > 0)
                    publishProgress(""
                            + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // Write In FileOutputStream.
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        }  catch (Exception e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void publishProgress(String percent) {
        // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
        // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
        // state
        downloadProgressWheel.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(percent));

    }
```

How can I set my `ProgressWheel` still updated when user returns back to it's associated activity.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is running or not when return back to Activity?

Comment: and you want the progress wheel to hide after the downlaod is completed?  in that case hide it in the Asyn's Post Execute method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I'm sure `AsyncTask` is running because after a while i can see the download is finished

Comment: @JohanV No I dont want the most important thing for me is set the download percent in `ProgressWheel` during download even after finishing the activity and then opening it again.

Comment: and is your progresswheel getting stuck at a percentage?

Comment: @JohanV no it doesnt when i open the activity again it show 0% percentage of download

Comment: ok , what if you set it to 100 in the on post execute method of the async task?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71376/discussion-between-milad-and-johan-v).